# Kivy: Self-updating label text

Tags: python, kivy

Let's say I have 3 classes: a "woking class" where stuff takes place, a label class and a class to contain them. 
For example the label class could be a status bar showing the status of something going on the working class. I wish I could find a way to make the label self-update the value to show, since this value is a value of the working class being changed inside the latter.

Here I have an example code

```
Builder.load_string('''
<CustomLabel>
    text: 'Value is {}'.format(root.value)

<WorkingClass>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    Button:
        text: 'Update'
        on_release: root.update()

<MainLayout>
    orientation: 'vertical'

''')

class CustomLabel(Label):
    value = NumericProperty()

class WorkingClass(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(WorkingClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.a = 5

    def update(self):
        self.a += 1
        print(self.a)

class MainLayout(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(MainLayout, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.workingClass = WorkingClass()
        self.customLabel = CustomLabel(value=self.workingClass.a)

        self.add_widget(self.customLabel)
        self.add_widget(self.workingClass)





class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Is there a way of doing it with properties or whatever? Becouse I don't want to need to manually update (sommehow) the label each time I change the value. Anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You're updating a property on `WorkingClass`, but that doesn't update the value on `CustomLabel` since you did a direct assignment instead of `bind`ing it. But yes, you can use `Property`s to make everything work automatically.

In `WorkingClass`:

```
class WorkingClass(BoxLayout):
    a = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs): ...
```

This makes `a` into a `Property` which you can bind to.

Then in `MainLayout`'s constructor:

```
self.workingClass = WorkingClass()
self.customLabel = CustomLabel(value=self.workingClass.a)
self.workingClass.bind(a=self.customLabel.setter('value'))
```

The last line says: "when the value of property `a` on `self.workingClass` changes, set the `value` property of `self.customLabel` to the same value"

Alternatively, you could just add the `Property` to `WorkingClass` above, then get rid of `MainLayout`'s constructor and use kv instead:

```
<MainLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'

    WorkingClass:
        id: working_class

    CustomLabel:
        value: working_class.a  # assigning one property to another in kv automatically binds
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about setters!I just noticed it's always you answering my kivy question so double thanks you!