# Update properties of a kivy widget while running code

Tags: python, refresh, kivy

I want to update the properties of a kivy widget while running something...

Example:

```
class app(App):
    def build(self):
        self.layout = Layout()
        self.name = Label(text = "john")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.name)
        return self.layout

    def update(self):
        for i in range(50): #keep showing the update
            self.name.text = str(i)
            #maybe some sleep here

obj = app()
obj.run()
obj.update()
```

This is gonna show me only the final result of the loop. I'd like to keep updating the label.text while the loop goes.

I looked for something like the bind(), setter() and ask_update() functions, but if are these funcs, I didn't get how to use them.

------------------ EDIT -----------------------

Trying to adapt to `inclement` answer (running the update function in other thread using Clock), I got the code below trying to follow the real idea of my problem, but still not working:

```
class main():
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    ... some code goes here ...

    def func(self):
        Clock.schedule_once(partial(self.app.update, self.arg_1, self.arg_2), 0)

class app(App):
    def build(self):
            self.main = main(self)
            self.layout = Layout()
            self.name = Label(text = "john")
            self.layout.add_widget(self.name)
            return self.layout

    ... some code goes here ...

    def update(self, dt, arg_1, arg_2):
        self.name = arg_1
        sleep(5)
        self.name = arg_2

obj = app()
obj.run()
```

I need to call the `func`function and make it update the label text exactly when I order the text change in `update` function.

Comment: Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817559/kivy-self-updating-label-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to avoid blocking the main thread. In most cases, it's convenient to just use kivy's clock. You can do something like the following.

```
from kivy.clock import Clock

class app(App):
    def build(self):
        self.layout = Layout()
        self.name = Label(text = "john")
        self.layout.add_widget(self.name)
        self.current_i = 0
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1)
        return self.layout

    def update(self, *args):
        self.name.text = str(self.current_i)
        self.current_i += 1
        if self.current_i >= 50:
            Clock.unschedule(self.update)
```

Comment: I've been trying to adapt your answer, but still not working, I edited my question following what you said.

Comment: `running the update function in other thread using Clock` <- Clock runs it in the *same* thread, and your sleep call still blocks this thread.

Comment: I'm gonna remove the sleep and find something else. I'll keep trying to do as you suggested to make it works. Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone still needs the answer, but it seems that your mistake is here:

```
def update(self, dt, arg_1, arg_2):
    self.name = arg_1
    sleep(5)
    self.name = arg_2
```

You either assign `arg1` and `arg2`, presumably strings, to the widget, which doesn't seem to make much sense. Or creating a new widget and reassigning it to the same variable, which is also not correct. Instead you can assign to property directly:

```
def update(self, dt, arg_1, arg_2):
    self.name.text = arg_1
    sleep(5)
    self.name.text = arg_2
```

Or you can create a StringProperty on your main object and bind `self.name.text` to it, but I personally prefer updating the screen manually. Explicit is better than implicit and all that.