# How to play a video of an image stack in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, user-interface, callback, kivy

I am writing a kivy GUI for some data analysis of an image stack (i.e. video) that I read in as a numpy array. I need to be able to play back the video, i.e. there would be a play button which triggers a for-loop to go through all the images of the stack and update the texture of an `Image` for every image of the stack.

I am unable to figure out how to do the last part.

I can generate an `Image` Widget and assign it a texture from a frame of the `np.array` like so (`a` is the `np.array` containing the image stack):

```
img = np.zeros((128, 128, 3))
img[:, :, 0] = a[0]   # I have to do it like this
img[:, :, 1] = a[0]   # b/c apparently it is not possible
img[:, :, 2] = a[0]   # to assign a grayscale image from a single 2D array
h, w, _ = img.shape
texture = Texture.create(size=(w, h))
texture.blit_buffer(img.flatten(), colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')
imgFrame = Image(size=(w, h), texture=texture)
```

This piece of code works to generate the `Image` Widget and have it display the first frame of the `a` array. However, I did not manage to update the texture of the `Image` if it is already generated beforehand.

The following code is a kind-of-working example. I now generate the `Image` Widget first and then assign the texture later. See the comments in the code -- updating the texture works only without the for-loop and also then I have to move/resize the window to trigger the redrawing of the texture.

```
import numpy as np

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


Builder.load_string('''
<BoxyBox>:
  w_img: img1

  FileChooserListView:
    id: filechooser
    rootpath: '/path/to/binary/data/'
    on_submit: root.readInBin(self.selection[0])
  ImgFrame:
    id: img1
''')

class BoxyBox(BoxLayout):

  w_img = ObjectProperty(None)

  def readInBin(self, fileName):
    xRes      = 128
    yRes      = 128
    nFrames   = 10000
    precision = np.uint16

    # read in binary data:
    f = open(fileName, 'r')
    a = np.fromfile(f, dtype=precision).reshape(nFrames, yRes, xRes)
    f.close()

    img = np.zeros((128, 128, 3))

    for i in range(a.shape[0]):   # if i remove the for-loop, and just use i = 0
    # i = 0                       # then this block works
      img[:, :, 0] = a[i]         # but not with the loop
      img[:, :, 1] = a[i]
      img[:, :, 2] = a[i]

      img = np.flipud(np.uint8(255*img/np.max(img)))


      # any of the following works to update the texture ONCE, but not in the loop:
      # also, it does not work 100% as intended -- it only redraws after moving the window

      # option 1:
      self.w_img.texture.blit_buffer(img.flatten(), colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')

      # option 2:
      #self.w_img.cbuffer = img.flatten()
      #self.w_img.populate_texture(self.w_img.texture)

    return a


class ImgFrame(Image):

  # these two functions are copied from
  # https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.texture.html#reloading-the-texture
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(ImgFrame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.texture = Texture.create(size=(128, 128), colorfmt='rgb', bufferfmt='ubyte')
    self.texture.add_reload_observer(self.populate_texture)

    # and load the data now.
    self.cbuffer = np.zeros((128, 128, 3), dtype = np.int8).flatten()
    self.populate_texture(self.texture)

  def populate_texture(self, texture):
    texture.blit_buffer(self.cbuffer)

class TextureTestApp(App):
  def build(self):
    return BoxyBox()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  TextureTestApp().run()
```

(Obviously, this is not how the program would run in the end, but for testing purposes I wanted to start the playback of the video right after loading it from the `FileChooser.)

I am unsure about the `add_reload_observer` method and the kivy documentation does not explain it properly. I also found ask_update() but did not manage to use it as intendet.

Maybe regardless of my example, my question is **How to play a video of an image stack in a numpy array?**, or, assuming I correctly found out that I have to draw the frames via a texture, then: **How to update and redraw the texture of a Widget from inside a function?**

---

EDIT:

I figured out that the issue is really with the for-loop. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42528021/kivy-label-text-does-not-update-during-for-loop) and  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27213545/update-properties-of-a-kivy-widget-while-running-code), the loop is blocking the main thread.
The solution should then be to use the kivy clock or threading to take care of updating the texture (or any other kivy property) from inside the loop.

The solutions suggested in the two threads above work for, e.g., changing the color of a rectangle, or the text of a label, etc. but they do not work for the texture.

I added the texture as `tex = ObjectProperty(None)` to the root widget, initialize it as a Kivy Texture in its `__init__` funktion and assign the texture of the Child-`Image` as `texture: root.tex` in kv.

Using the Clock to schedule an update function works in principle, but also then I only see the updating texture when moving the window around. So I am still **missing the command to trigger the redrawing of the texture**.

Comment: Don't know if this would work, but try creating a new `Texture` object for each video frame and then do `self.w_img.texture = new_texture`. The `texture` property change should trigger a redraw of the `Image`.

Comment: Are you basically asking how to subset the array? If you are on frame `n`, in a `128, 128, N` array, use the 2D array `a[:, :, n]`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Thanks! This results in almost the same behavior as the two options I described above: It works without the loop, but it does not do anything to the texture (not even draw the first frame) if used inside the loop. The only thing is that it draws the Texture directly, without the need to move/resize the Window.

Comment: @MadPhysicist no, that's not what I am asking ;) -- in my code example `n` is the first dimension, and thus I can get the corresponding 2D array by `a[n]`.