# how to make self updating clock label in kivy?

Tags: python, label, kivy, clock

I want to make a Label which acts as a clock and gets updated every second just as in [making-a-clock-in-kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923321/making-a-clock-in-kivy) link but in the status bar.

I want the label in *status.kv* file with *id: _tnd* to act as a clock. 
The print statement in the update function (test_gui.py) does work and prints the date and time in the console after every second, but the label is not getting updated. I am pretty much confused right now!. It might be a silly mistake, but How do I do it?

I have 3 files

1. test_gui.py
2. test.kv
3. status.kv

test_gui.py file

```
import time
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Builder.load_file('status.kv')

class Status(BoxLayout):
    _change = StringProperty()
    _tnd = ObjectProperty(None)
    def update(self,*args):
        self.time = time.asctime()
        self._change = str(self.time)
        self._tnd.text = str(self.time)
        print self._change

class C(BoxLayout):
    pass


class TimeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.load_kv('test.kv')
        crudeclock = Status()
        Clock.schedule_interval(crudeclock.update, 1)
        return C()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TimeApp().run()
```

test.kv file

```
    <C>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: "Button"
            Label:
                text: "Label"
        Status:
```

status.kv file

```
    <Status>:
    size_hint: 1,.1
    _tnd: _tnd
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Label:
        text:'Current Date and Time:'
    Label:
        id: _tnd
        text: root._change +' time'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23817559/kivy-self-updating-label-text

Comment: @stark   In the link it updates the value when an event occurs (button is clicked).
But here it needs to be updated without any event.
Value of **self.time** which is a string (changes every second) to be stored in **self._change** and updated in the label automatically.
But here self._change is always **empty** .

Comment: Where do you bind the label to the variable?

Comment: @stark The answer by bj0 solved my problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.  The biggest is in your `build(self)` function:

```
def build(self):
    self.load_kv('test.kv')
    crudeclock = Status()
    Clock.schedule_interval(crudeclock.update, 1)
    return C()
```

You are creating a `Status` object and setting up a clock to call it's update function, but it is **not** part of your display.  It is a separate, independent instance of `Status` that is not attached to your widget tree.  When you return `C()`, it creates the widget tree defined in test.kv with its own, internal `Status` instance that is not being updated.

The second issue is that you are binding the `Label`'s text field to a property in the .kv file, and then also manually changing it in the callback.  I'm guessing you tried one and then the other to see if either worked.  Both will work if you are using the right object, but you only want to use one.

As far as accessing the right `Status` object, the simplest way to fix your code is to tag it in test.kv, then access it in `build(self)`:

```
<C>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout:
            Button:
                text: "Button"
            Label:
                text: "Label"
        Status:
            id: stat
```

and:

```
def build(self):
    self.load_kv('test.kv')
    c = C()
    stat = c.ids.stat  # this is the right object
    Clock.schedule_interval(stat.update, 1)
    return c
```

**An alternative**, since you really only need to keep time once for your whole app, is to put the property in your app class and bind to it in the kv file:

```
    time = StringProperty()

    def update(self, *args):
        self.time = str(time.asctime()) # + 'time'?

    def build(self):
        self.load_kv('test.kv')
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1)
        return C()
```

and

```
<Status>:
    size_hint: 1,.1
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Label:
        text:'Current Date and Time:'
    Label:
        text: app.time
```

Which looks a little cleaner.