# How to set Font size or Label size to fit all device

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

How to set kivy font size or label size so that it will fit all phone-device screen? (fit by means does not overlap with the boundary, rectangle, or even the screen)

I know the Buttons and some other Widgets in Kivy have `size_hint`. This `size_hint` does not give desired result.

Also, setting the `font_size` can do the trick, but it will be difficult to automate using this. Now close solution is by setting and getting the `Window.size` in *cm*, and use `font_size` in *cm*.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually interesting question.

Usually you pass text, font, font size and region that limits the text (`text_size` in kivy label) to renderer and get texture of some size from it. What you want is knowing label's texture size to get font size. I guess it's theoretically possible, but you'll need to do all calculations manually in Kivy.

May us do some workaround? Instead of trying to calculate font size, we can just use some very large one and scale final texture to match given size. Scaling with ration keeping can be easily done with Kivy's `Image` widget, for example. Proof-of-Concept (Python 3):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyLabel(Image):
    text = StringProperty('')

    def on_text(self, *_):
        # Just get large texture:
        l = Label(text=self.text)
        l.font_size = '1000dp'  # something that'll give texture bigger than phone's screen size
        l.texture_update()
        # Set it to image, it'll be scaled to image size automatically:
        self.texture = l.texture


class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyLabel(text='Test test test')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Far from ideal, but does job.

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is Out-of-box. I tried the same concept in Python 2 and it did not seem to work, only gives blank white.  My code is in the post. In yours : `on_text` or `on_texture`?

Comment: @Arief no code is correct. I just checked and it'll work in Python 2 also - without any changes. `on_text` - is not some member of class `Image`, but function that automatically called when `text` property changes. Read this [link](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#observe-using-on-propname) for details.

Answer (score 7):

To scale the font of the button or label when resizing window, I use *font_size*
in kv file and divide *self.width* by some number:

```
Label:
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            text: "Some label text"
            font_size: self.width/20
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, with Window.size, you could calculate the Window's diagonal, multiply it by a self-chosen factor (it should be between 0 and 1) and then use it to automatically update your label's fontsize [(click here to see another stack overflow article on how to automatically update your label)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30193240/how-to-make-self-updating-clock-label-in-kivy).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option that just uses a normal Button (could also be a Label).  I'm using it to reduce font size to fit a fixed-size widget.  It took a while to understand, but, the label text is painted on to the texture 'object' using the current font_size, so, after the label text is set, the texture_size will show how wide that text is.  If it's wider than the widget in question, reduce the size and try again.  You could do the inverse to increase the font_size to fill up the parent.  Here's a snippet from some working code, hopefully it's enough to get the gist across:

```
# for long names, reduce font size until it fits in its widget
m=self.defaultTextHeightMultiplier
self.keypad.ids.nameButton.font_size=self.keypad.ids.nameButton.height*m
self.keypad.ids.nameButton.texture_update()
while m>0.3 and self.keypad.ids.nameButton.texture_size[0]>self.keypad.ids.nameButton.width:
    m=m-0.05
    self.keypad.ids.nameButton.font_size=self.keypad.ids.nameButton.height*m
    self.keypad.ids.nameButton.texture_update()
```

Or to make it a separate function:

```
def setTextToFit(self,widget,text):
    widget.text=text
    # for long names, reduce font size until it fits in its widget
    m=self.defaultTextHeightMultiplier
    widget.font_size=widget.height*m
    widget.texture_update()
    while m>0.3 and widget.texture_size[0]>widget.width:
        m=m-0.05
        widget.font_size=widget.height*m
        widget.texture_update()
```

That code could probably be shortened by emulating a do-while loop; it could be called with:

```
self.setTextToFit(self.keypad.ids.nameButton,theText)
```